# Angular factory not available in service unit test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

So I'm writing a unit test for a method in a service that needs to use a factory defined elsewhere. How do I include a mock factory instead?

As an alternative, I can include the real factory, but catch everything with httpBackend, but I would prefer not to since the factory itself isn't tested.

The service:

```
"use strict";

rmtg.service('meetingHelper', ['Job', function(Job) {
...
this.getStatus = function (meeting, callback) {
    if (!meeting.ReferencedJobs || meeting.ReferencedJobs.length < 1){
        callback('Error: No Associated Jobs');
        return
    } else if (meeting.ReferencedJobs.length == 1){
        var job = Job.get(meeting.ReferencedJobs[0]);
        console.log(job);
        callback('one');
    }
};
```

The tests so far:

```
describe("meetingHelper service", function(){
    beforeEach(module("rmtg"));

    var meetingHelper;
    beforeEach(inject(function(_meetingHelper_, Job){
        meetingHelper = _meetingHelper_;
    }));

    var mockMeeting = {};
    var mockUser = {};
    var mockScope = {};
    describe('.getStatus', function () {
    beforeEach(function() {
        mockScope.callback = function () {
        };
        spyOn(mockScope, 'callback');
    });

    it('should call the callback function if there are no Referrenced Jobs', function () {
        meetingHelper.getStatus(mockMeeting, mockScope.callback);
        expect(mockScope.callback).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Error: No Associated Jobs');
    });
    it('should call the callback function if there is exactly one Referrenced Jobs', function () {
        mockMeeting.ReferencedJobs = ["f"];
        meetingHelper.getStatus(mockMeeting, mockScope.callback);
        expect(mockScope.callback).toHaveBeenCalledWith('one');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just register another factory on top of the one that is already registered:

```
beforeEach(function() {
  var mockService = ...;
  var testMod = angular.module('testMod', ['rmtg'])
      .value('serviceNameToMock', mockService);
  module(testMod.name);
});
```

As indicated in the comments, this can be even more terse:

```
beforeEach(function() {
  var mockService = ...;
  module("rmtg", { serviceNameToMock: mockService });
});
```

looking at the docs for [angular.mock.module](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.module), it isn't immediately obvious that `module` takes multiple arguments, but a quick look at the source makes it a bit more clear.

Comment: It can be as simple as `module("rmtg", { serviceNameToMock: mockService })`.

Comment: @estus -- Awesome... For some reason I never realized that `angular.mock.module` accepted multiple arguments...